# How to set textview in a for loop

Tags: android

I would like to get all `getDaystime()` in my `TextView`, but currently only the last `getDaystime()` is displayed. Here is what I have so far:

```
List<WeekDays> weekDaysList = place.getWeekDayList();

        if(weekDaysList.size()>0)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<weekDaysList.size();i++)
            {
                WeekDays days = weekDaysList.get(i);
                //String openhours += days.getDaystime();
                //Log.d("WeekDaysView",days.getDaystime());
                weekDays.setText(days.getDaystime());
            }


        }
```

Here is the logcat result:

> 11-23 17:24:55.553 32297-32297/com.softtoll.ncf D/WeekDaysView: Monday: 9:00 AM – 7:00 PM
>   11-23 17:24:55.553 32297-32297/com.softtoll.ncf D/WeekDaysView: Tuesday: 9:00 AM – 7:00 PM
>   11-23 17:24:55.553 32297-32297/com.softtoll.ncf D/WeekDaysView: Wednesday: 9:00 AM – 7:00 PM
>   11-23 17:24:55.553 32297-32297/com.softtoll.ncf D/WeekDaysView: Thursday: 9:00 AM – 7:00 PM
>   11-23 17:24:55.553 32297-32297/com.softtoll.ncf D/WeekDaysView: Friday: 9:00 AM – 7:00 PM
>   11-23 17:24:55.553 32297-32297/com.softtoll.ncf D/WeekDaysView: Saturday: 9:00 AM – 7:00 PM
>   11-23 17:24:55.553 32297-32297/com.softtoll.ncf D/WeekDaysView: Sunday: Closed

Comment: post your question with small description so viewers can understand your problem otherwise you get down voted again and again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
List<WeekDays> weekDaysList = place.getWeekDayList();

        if(weekDaysList.size()>0)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<weekDaysList.size();i++)
            {
                WeekDays days = weekDaysList.get(i);
                //String openhours += days.getDaystime();
                //Log.d("WeekDaysView",days.getDaystime());
              weekDays.append("WeekDaysView:\n" + days.getDaystime() + "\n");
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using `TextView.setText()` method. Try using the `TextView.append()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You Should use
 [**`append(CharSequence text)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

> Convenience method to append the specified text to the `TextView's` display buffer, upgrading it to EDITABLE if it was not already editable.

**use this**

```
weekDays.append(days.getDaystime()+" \n");
```

**instead of this**

```
weekDays.setText(days.getDaystime());
```

> OR use **[`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)**

```
 if(weekDaysList.size()>0)
 {   
   StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();

   for(int i = 0;i<weekDaysList.size();i++)
      {
         WeekDays days = weekDaysList.get(i);

         myString.append(days.getDaystime()+ " \n");

       }

     weekDays.setText(myString);
}
```

> Don't forgot set **`textView.setMaxLines(int lines);`** property

Comment: Yes it is now showing but i want to view the every text in new Line here is showing on same line just like this----- Monday:9:00AM-7:00PMTuesday:9:00AM-7:00PM and so on but i want to view as                    Monday:9:00AM - 7:00 PM                                                                                 Tuesday:9:00AM - 7:00 PM                                                                           and so on..

Answer (score 1):

I assume your textview is `weekDays`

So with `weekDays.setText(days.getDaystime());` you're overriding the text for every item. You probably want to create a string in the for loop and set the text after the loop has finished or use the `TextView.append()` method.